# Why was the Borg Queen Recast?

Tags: star-trek, behind-the-scenes, borg, star-trek-picard

Picard season 2 will feature the Borg Queen, but it's been [recast](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-borg-queen-original-return-alice-krige/) with actress, Annie Wersching.

The linked article says:

> Since Alice Krige returned to voice the Borg Queen in Star Trek: Lower
> Decks, Trekkers may wonder why the cyborg monarch was recast with
> Annie Wersching in Star Trek: Picard. **One possibility is that COVID-19
> protocols may have hampered Krige from resuming her iconic role.**
> Meanwhile, Star Trek: Picard films in Los Angeles, and they likely
> opted to cast Wersching as the Borg Queen since she's a fine actress
> known for her roles in 24 and Marvel's Runaways, plus she also
> conveniently lives in LA.

It's not a definitive statement, but is COVID the only reason why they didn't cast Alice Krige or Susanna Thompson? Alice Krige did reprise the role in Lower Decks, although this was probably done remotely.

Comment: All sides are apt to present things diplomatically without casting anyone in negative light or reveal any personal or medical conditions about anyone. Entertainment media is typically in best position to get the most information on these kinds of questions, and at this time this is likely to be the only truth we’ll be informed of. Wait a few years and one side or other might then reveal more like “I was all ready to play the Queen but those cheap bastards wouldn’t pay to fly my poodle Fifi with me.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue - That's what happened to Laurence Fishburne, in The Matrix: Ressurections. He claimed he was never contacted about the role, but wishes them well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alice Krige is currently filming a remake of [The Texas Chainsaw Massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Chainsaw_Massacre_(2021_film)) (the original was in 1974), though the schedule would seem to indicate that it is in post-production, there are invariably ADR (additional dialogue recordings) scenes and any re-shoots that crop-up.

She's also involved in her voice-over work for Star-Trek Lower Decks.

There's also the little dwelt-on fact of her age, Alice being 67 at the time of this answer (28 June 1954, DOB.), the studios are notorious for [casting in a younger age](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/oliver-burkeman-column/2015/may/12/the-cult-of-youth-cheats-young-and-old-alike-lets-reclaim-adulthood) range to attract younger audiences.

Comment: I would have still liked to see AK or ST in the role.

Comment: Picard being Amazon based? That's flatly incorrect. Picard is a Paramount+ network show, just like Lower Decks in terms of ownership and production. (distribution platform may vary depending on region)

Comment: @NKCampbell That'll teach me for relying on not-research, I shan't do that again. Seems to have been originally made for CBS studios too. Much appreciated, edited.

Comment: yeah it was originally CBS All-Access, which then had a name change to Paramount+ - s'all good